# ¿Cómo agrupar sólo por una columna con SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Tengo este `SELECT` en SQL Server:

```
SELECT p.Nombre, p.Apellido, c.TipoDoc, d.Nombre AS DescriTipoDoc, c.Documento AS NroDoc, c.NroEval AS Evaluacion, c.FecAtencion AS UltModif, c.idMedico FROM indiseMED_AccConsulta c 
    JOIN indiseMED_Documento d ON d.CodDoc = c.TipoDoc 
    JOIN indiseMED_Personas p ON p.TipoDoc = c.TipoDoc AND p.Documento = c.Documento 
    WHERE c.FecAtencion>='01/01/1800' AND c.FecAtencion<='12/31/2999';
```

lo cual me devuelve el siguiente resultado (Obviamente que sin los guiones, eso lo puse yo para acomodarlo y que se entienda):

| Nombre | Apellido | TipoDoc | DescriTipoDoc | NroDoc | Evaluacion | UltModif | idMedico |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JUAN | PEREZ | 1 | DNI | 99999999 | 22094 | 2021-07-06 00:00:00.000 | Diego |
| JUAN | PEREZ | 1 | DNI | 99999999 | 22094 | 2021-07-13 00:00:00.000 | Diego |
| PEDRO | GOMEZ | 1 | DNI | 99999999 | 22093 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00.000 | Diego |
| PEDRO | GOMEZ | 1 | DNI | 99999999 | 22093 | 2021-07-02 00:00:00.000 | Diego |
| PEDRO | GOMEZ | 1 | DNI | 99999999 | 22093 | 2021-07-05 00:00:00.000 | Diego |

Lo que yo necesito que me muestre es el primer registro que encuentre con el mismo Nro de `Evaluacion`, es decir así:

| Nombre | Apellido | TipoDoc | DescriTipoDoc | NroDoc | Evaluacion | UltModif | idMedico |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JUAN | PEREZ | 1 | DNI | 99999999 | 22094 | 2021-07-06 00:00:00.000 | Diego |
| PEDRO | GOMEZ | 1 | DNI | 99999999 | 22093 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00.000 | Diego |

Lo que quise hacer es agregar un `GROUP BY c.NroEval` al final de la sentencia SQL pero me dice que tengo que hacerlo por todos los campos que voy a hacer el `SELECT`.

**De qué manera puedo hacer esta consulta?**

Comment: Debería funcionarte haciendo el `GROUP BY` con los mismos campos que tienes en el `SELECT`, algo así `GROUP BY p.Nombre, p.Apellido, c.TipoDoc, d.Nombre, c.Documento, c.NroEval, c.FecAtencion, c.idMedico`

Comment: Por favor, defini "primer registro", porque las bases de datos no tienen un concepto de primer o ultimo registro, salvo que la consulta este ordenada....

Comment: Pareciera que te alcanza con hacer un `MIN( c.FecAtencion)`  y agrupar así `GROUP BY p.Nombre, p.Apellido, c.TipoDoc, d.Nombre, c.Documento, c.NroEval, c.Atencion, c.idMedico`

Comment: @JosueArriola Lo hice, pero me muestra lo mismo que el primer SELECT porque el campo UltModif es diferente

Comment: @gbianchi lo que necesito es que me muestre el 2do recuadro... por "primer registro" me refiero al primer registro que encuentra el SELECT, tal cual el 2do recuadro

Comment: Otra vez.. no hay primer registro que encuentre el select, los select tiran los registros de forma aleatoria (aunque pienses que no).. asi que tenes que definir a que llamas primer registro.. el de menor fecha? el de menor id? el de menor nombre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta sentencia creo que te puede ayudar:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.Nombre, p.Apellido, c.TipoDoc, d.Nombre AS DescriTipoDoc, c.Documento AS NroDoc, c.NroEval AS Evaluacion, c.FecAtencion AS UltModif, c.idMedico,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.NroEval ORDER BY c.FecAtencion DESC) AS [ROW NUMBER] 
    FROM indiseMED_AccConsulta c 
        JOIN indiseMED_Documento d ON d.CodDoc = c.TipoDoc 
        JOIN indiseMED_Personas p ON p.TipoDoc = c.TipoDoc AND p.Documento = c.Documento 
        WHERE c.FecAtencion>='01/01/1800' AND c.FecAtencion<='12/31/2999';
) DATA
WHERE DATA.[ROW NUMBER] = 1
```

*PARTITION BY c.NroEval ORDER BY c.FecAtencion DESC* agrupa los registros que tienen el mismo c.NroEval ordenándolos de forma descendente (los más recientes primero). La función ROW_NUMBER lo que hace es numero cada una de estas agrupaciones.

Quedando algo por el estilo:

```
Nombre | Apellido | TipoDoc | DescriTipoDoc | NroDoc -- | Evaluacion | UltModif ------------------| idMedico | ROW_NUMBER

JUAN ---| PEREZ --| 1 --------| DNI ----------- | 99999999 | 22094 ------| 2021-07-06 00:00:00.000 | Diego | 1

JUAN ---| PEREZ --| 1 --------| DNI ----------- | 99999999 | 22094 ------| 2021-07-13 00:00:00.000 | Diego | 2

PEDRO- | GOMEZ -| 1 --------| DNI ---------- | 99999999 | 22093 ------| 2021-07-01 00:00:00.000 | Diego | 1

PEDRO- | GOMEZ -| 1 --------| DNI ---------- | 99999999 | 22093 ------| 2021-07-02 00:00:00.000 | Diego | 2

PEDRO- | GOMEZ -| 1 --------| DNI ---------- | 99999999 | 22093 ------| 2021-07-05 00:00:00.000 | Diego | 3
```

Como puedes ver el ROW_NUMBER te indica el número de fila dentro del grupo (no el número de fila teniendo en cuenta todos los registros). Por eso, al final lo que se hace es quedarte únicamente con los registros cuyo ROW_NUMBER es 1.

Espero que te sirva...